# Extremely strange for loop behavior in Matlab

Tags: matlab, debugging, loops

When attempting to write a for loop to increment from 1 to the end of an array, Matlab throws an error saying that I attempted to access the 0th array element, which doesn't exist.  Here's the snippet in question:

```
     function [adjMatNew] = delete(obj, adjMat)
        [~, n] = size(adjMat);
        adjMatNew = adjMat;
        for i = 1:n
            if adjMat(obj.number, i) ~= 0
                adjList(i) = i
            end 
        end

        for j = 1:numel(adjList)
            for k = 1:numel(adjList)
                if j ~= k
                    adjMatNew(adjList(k), adjList(j)) = 1;
                end
            end
        end

        adjMatNew(obj.number, :) = 0;
        adjMatNew(:, obj.number) = 0;
    end
```

I can't think of any possible reason why, in the for loops above, the loop would start at 0.  Changing the beginning increment variable from 1 to 2 fixed the issue and the function worked as intended, but it doesn't seem like the right fix.  Does anybody have an explanation for this?

Comment: It's always handy to tell us *which* line the error happens on.  In fact, just add the entire error message stack trace!  For example, the error *could* have been on the `if adjMat(obj.number, i) ~= 0` line, the `adjList(i) = i` line, the `adjMatNew(adjList(k), adjList(j)) = 1;` line, the `adjMatNew(obj.number, :) = 0;` line, or the `adjMatNew(:, obj.number) = 0;` line.  Why make us guess - just tell us, and we can help you faster!

Comment: Also, just as a general remark: handle class destructors (`delete()`) may not have more than one argument; see [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_oop/handle-class-destructors.html).

Comment: "Break on error: always" is _the_ most helpful debugger option - inspecting the program state at the point of the error makes the cause a lot easier to track down. Also, vectorising those loops can make the code more robust as well as cleaner and faster: `adjList = find(adjMat(obj.number,:))` won't contain any stray zeros, by definition.

Answer (score 3):

Without any help or comments, it's not very clear what you're actually attempting to do; however, in the line
`adjMatNew(adjList(k), adjList(j)) = 1;`
you implicitly assume that `adjList` is never zero. Since that is apparently the case, you get the error.

Comment: From how `adjList` is constructed, it almost certainly _does_ contain zeros, unless _every_ column of `adjMat` matches.

Comment: adjMat is an adjacency matrix for a graph containing a certain number of vertices.  I generated adjList because each row in the matrix essentially corresponds to a list of the neighbors of a vertex with the number corresponding to that row.  Could you elaborate on why the list almost definitely contains zeros if I'm trying to simply pull out the nonzero elements from a particular row of a matrix?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in other comments/answers, the issue is where you construct `adjList`.

```
  for i = 1:n
     if adjMat(obj.number, i) ~= 0
          adjList(i) = i
     end 
  end
```

Let's consider what happens in three different situations where `n = 3`:

1) If all of `adjMat(obj.number, 1:3)` are `~=0`, each loop

```
adjList(1) = 1;
adjList(2) = 2;
adjList(3) = 3;

output: adjList = [1,2,3];
```

This case shouldn't throw an error.

2) If `adjMat(obj.number, 3)` is zero:

```
adjList(1) = 1;
adjList(2) = 2;
% adjList(3) not set

output: adjList = [1,2];
```

No error here, either.

3) If `adjMat(obj.number, 2)` is zero:

```
adjList(1) = 1;
% adjList(2) not set
adjList(3) = 3;
```

Since `adjList(2)` is not set, when calling `adjList(3) = 3;`, MATLAB needs there to be some value for `adjList(2)`.  By default, this is handled by filling with zeros to make the matrix the right size:

output: adjList = [1 0 3];

This causes the error.

As suggested in the comments by Notlikethat, `adjList = find(adjMat(obj.number,:))` would be good way of replacing this loop.  In this case, it only returns the positions of the non zero elements, so in the third case above, the output would be `adjList = [1 3]`.